# How to document multiple return values in Numpydoc format?

Tags: python, pycharm, tuples, type-hinting, numpydoc

I am trying to document a tuple return value using numpy docstring format, but can't make it work with pycharm type hinting.

I have tried multiple ways, and even found one that was working for the type, but did not allow me to add a description for each of its elements.

Example of a function to document:

```py
def function():
    foo = 42
    bar = {
        example : 1337,
        dictionary : 46,
    }
    return foo, bar
```

Now, one way I could go about to document it is:

```py
def function():
    """
    This is the function summary.

    Returns
    -------
    foobar : tuple[int,[dict[string, int]]
        This is a description of the return type
    """
    foo = 42
    bar = {
        'example' : 1337,
        'dictionary' : 46,
    }
    return foo, bar
```

This would grant me a description and the right return type hinting, but not individual descriptions for each elements, which I would like.

Here is a non-working example of what I am trying to achieve:

```py
def function():
    """
    This is the function summary.

    Returns
    -------
    foo : int
        This is an int
    bar : [dict[string, int]
        This is a dictionary
    """
    foo = 42
    bar = {
        'example' : 1337,
        'dictionary' : 46,
    }
    return foo, bar
```

Comment: I have the same issue - did you ever figure out how to document each of the tuple's elements individually?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `function` return value is annotated as `tuple[int, dict[string, int]]`, its documentation is rendered correctly, but there is an issue with inferring type for `function()[1]["key"]`. Feel free to file an issue in public PyCharm tracker https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/PY.

Comment: It does indeed document correctly, but I'd like to document the tuple's elements individually.